# How to compress a folder to zip?

Tags: python, linux, email, compression, zip

I have a folder in my directory which consists of CSV files. I am using Python and generating some CSV files with data through code dynamically. So everytime when the code runs, CSV files will be created in a folder called `csv` (for example).

I had scheduled this code to run for every 10 days through cron jobs. So for every 10 days the Python code runs and the CSV files will be created in the `csv` folder.

Now i want to compress the `csv` folder with `zip` and want to send an email with this ZIP file as  an attachment.

1. Is it possible to compress a folder with CSV files tot the ZIP format?
2. After compressing, is it possible to send this compressed ZIP as an email attachement?

If so, can anyone please let me know how to do it Is it possible to do the above stuff through Python? Or we can do this through linux commands?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way would be to run a separate cron job to do the zipping and emailing:

`zip -r - csv | uuencode | mail -s "csv zips for $(date)" foo@bar.com`

If you run the above as a cron job, make sure that you `cd` into the parent directory first. So if `csv` is `/home/foo/csv`:

`cd /home/foo && zip -r csv | uuencode | mail -s "csv zips for $(date)" foo@bar.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
import zipfile
import smtplib

def archive_log(src, dst):
  """
  Archiving log file to zip
  """
  zip = zipfile.ZipFile(dst, 'w')
  zip.write(src, os.path.basename(src), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
  zip.close()

 def send_email_report2(self):
    SEND_TO = ['xxx@yyy.com']
    SMTP_IP = '0.0.0.0'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = 'xxx@yyy'
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(SEND_TO)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = 'Subject'

    msg.attach(MIMEText('bodu text'))

    for file_link in link_attachments:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload(open(file_link, "rb").read())
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(file_link))
        msg.attach(part)

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_IP)
    smtp.sendmail('xxx1@yyy.com', SEND_TO, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()
```

Comment: but in the above code where the archive_log function and send_email_report2 function will be called ?

Comment: `archive_log('1.csv', '1.zip')

link_attachments = ['1.zip', '2.zip']

send_email_report2()`